# Silencing all stdout during bootup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, upstart

I am looking for a completely silent bootup of my Ubuntu Server 13.04 installation (dumped to file rather than stdout). What I want is the screen to be blacked out (eventually replaced with a logo) until my system logs in.

I have silenced the commands in bash, but it looks like I still get commands coming from 'Upstart' and possibly some other services.

Comment: Why would anyone want this?  Also, was the machine be stored in a server closet in your home or business, or was it in a user-facing location (e.g. in a client's storefront window)?

Answer (score 3):

In your `/etc/default/grub` file, set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to `"quiet splash"`.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Then run `update-grub` as root.

Grub is your bootloader. It loads kernels. It has a menu. You see the Grub menu on boot. It might be purple. Linux kernel accepts arguments. The variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` lists the default arguments to add to Grub menu entries for Linux kernel. `update-grub` generates the menu entries.

The text you are seeing on boot is output from the kernel ring buffer (kernel log). You can read messages from the kernel ring buffer with `dmesg`.

```
dmesg | less
```

---

Upstart supports a `-q / --quiet` flag to reduce its output to errors only. Your kernel will pass any arguments that it does not recognize to your init system, so you can add the flag to the default command line like so:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash --quiet"
```

For more information about Upstart's supported flags, see the [Upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#command-line-options).

Comment: I have gotten that far for eliminating the kernel process output, but there is still output that is occurring before I get to login, which I believe is from Upstart.

Comment: @jdwiegman: Could you please provide a sample of that output?

Comment: @EvenTeitelman, I have a [screenshot](http://imgur.com/mKXBiTN) loaded and a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sejOXOFkGXw). The video doesn't quiet capture it, but it goes Bios logo, black, a couple lines of linux bootup text, black, then the text from the screenshot, then into my login.

Comment: @jdwiegman: I have added a bit to my answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: that didn't seem to change much. After some more research I believe its related to Plymouth, and it seems `plymouthd` is crashing, which is preventing the splash screen from covering the log text. Investigating it which is hard with the Ubuntu forums down right now.

Comment: @jdwiegman: You could try asking a quesiton over on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/). It shouldn't be considered cross-posting if you ask something along the lines of, "Why is the text not hidden by Plymouth?"

Answer (score 0):

I (partially) figured this out. The output I am seeing is coming from Plymouth. I did not have any plymouth-themes installed, so plymouth reverts to a verbose display. I tried making my own plymouth theme (a simple logo display) but it would not work properly. Finally I installed and modified `plymouth-theme-script` and that worked, except I had a final bit of text displayed just before my application launched.

The other part of why I was still seeing text is I had no Window Manager installed, my bootup just launched a `.bashrc` in TTY1 that had a startx command.  When I installed nodm, that launches directly into TTY7 from Plymouth eliminating the remainder of the text display.

Comment: I recently did a 14.04 upgrade and noticed that the splash is now completely quiet as it should have been, looks like a plymouth bug in 13.04.